# New document from mongoose method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to extend model with new method 'create'. It will check requirements for document creation, create additional documents and so on.
Usually I call

```
var user = new User({});
```

But how can I create document from mongoose method itself? I.e.

```
User.methods.create = function(userObject,callback){
    //some checks
    var doc = ???;
    doc.save(function(err){
       if(err) return callback(err);
       //saving done
       callback(null,doc);
    });
}
```

**UPD:**

Thx to @chridam's answer my final code now looks like this:

```
User.statics.create = function(userObject,callback){
    //some checks
    var doc = this.model('User')(userObject);
    doc.save(function(err){
       if(err) return callback(err);
       //saving done
       callback(null,doc);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statics will allow for defining functions that exist directly on your Model, so instead of an instance model (like you have tried), define a **[static](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics)** method on the `User` class. Example:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({ firstname: String, lastname: String });

// assign a function to the "statics" object of our userSchema
userSchema.statics.create = function (userObject) {
    console.log('Creating user');
    // use Function.prototype.call() to call the Model.create() function with the model you need
    return mongoose.Model.create.call(this.model('User'), userObject);
};
```

Comment: So, the 'static' method, defined in Schema will be method for all documents created from Model, while 'instance' method is a method for one document. Did I understood you correctly?

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to just use `return this.create(userObject, callback)` in the static method instead? You're also missing the callback part.

Comment: I think it's ES6 style with Promises. Since I sill use callbacks I used `var doc = this.model('User')(userObject);` and static methods after all :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not answering your question exactly, but it may be what you are looking for.

check out the mongoose middleware
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

There is a pre-save hook where you can do some validation and other things such as document creation.

Comment: Yeah, I know about middleware and pre-save, but I took 'create' method only as an example. There will be more methods that will create documents.